# Git rebase gets other commits from different branch in my PR

Tags: git, github, merge, rebase

I am working on a feature branch say f1. After working on same changes, creating a PR, I push those changes to master.

Instead of deleting the branch, I continue working on f1. I merge master to bring in other changes from master into f1. When I create another PR from f1, the commit section under PR has commits from other branches. How can I avoid commits in PR history other than the ones from f1 that I am currently dealing with?

Comment: Can you add the git log of both the branches `f1` and `master`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please, add some visualization by editing your explanation. It is hard to get what you are saying.

Comment: The title of your question mentions "rebase", but it doesn't look like you performed any rebase action. Can you either fix the title, or edit your question to reflect what actions you performed ?

Answer (score 0):

> I merge master to bring in other changes from master into f1.

Ideally, you avoid merging master to anything: the best practice is to merge or rebase other branches to `master`.

In your case:

```
m--m--m--m--m--m---M
       \          / (PR1)
        f1--f1--F1
                  \
                   f1--f1--f1 (f1: want to do PR2)
```

In order to branch what master has, and make sure at the same time PR2 will only include your new commits from f1 branch (new after PR1 that is), you do a `rebase --onto`, using F1 as the last commit before your first PR.

```
git rebase --onto master F1 f1

                                      \
                     f1'--f1'--f1' (f1: want to do PR2)
                    /
m--m--m--m--m--m---M
       \          / (PR1)
        f1--f1--F1
```

Now you can make your PR2 (second pull-request): it will include only the right commits.